# Open Bootstrap modal of different sizes at one common point via common css or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a project in which there are multiple Bootstrap modal's of different sizes. I want to change the position of all the modal at one specific point on the screen. 
I am attaching sample code in which there are 3 modals of different sizes. Modal 1 opens at proper position because i have overridden the default position properties,but the other two modal i.e. 2 and 3 are not opening at that point.
One solution is that i assign all modals a different ID and then position each modal via css but that would lead to inconsistency in design. I am unable to find common solution.

**NOTE**

I have more than 500 modal all are of different size i don't want to specify position of each modal. Is there anything i can dynamically capture screen size/modal size and align my modal to one single point

```css
.modal {
  top: 21px;
  left: -290px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Modal 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Modal 2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Modal 3</button>

<!-- MODAL 1 -->

<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is Default Size Modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- MODAL 2 -->

<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:20%">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is small Modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- MODAL 3 -->

<div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:90% !important; max-width:100% !important;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is Big Modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing `!important` CSS declarations? Perhaps Bootstrap is overwriting your style changes..

Comment: calc() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to use [`!important`](https://appendto.com/2016/04/css-important-rule-how-to-use-it-correctly/?nabe=4834138299564032:0,5488687288942592:0,5685334715400192:0,6035677076783104:0,6118337346273280:4&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F) CSS declarations as below, if you want to forcibly use the styles on all instances of `.modal`:

Note: this will look terrible until appropriate CSS has been added which suitable for all modal dialogues, but the idea is that the CSS is being applied to all instances.

```css
.modal-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Modal 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Modal 2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Modal 3</button>

<!-- MODAL 1 -->

<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is Default Size Modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- MODAL 2 -->

<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:20%">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is small Modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- MODAL 3 -->

<div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:90% !important; max-width:100% !important;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is Big Modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You notice all the modal have different co-ordinate for top-left posiiton

Comment: Notice your question - "I want to change the position of all the modal at _one specific point on the screen_. I am attaching sample code in which there are 3 modals of different sizes. Modal 1 opens at proper position because i have overridden the default position properties,but the other two modal i.e. 2 and 3 are not opening at that point." This, to me, means that you want all `.modal` to inherit same css so I would suggest updating your question so it isn't as misleading.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but to me it seems like you want to specify a "start" position of every `.modal` (not modify the actual size).. In which case, would CSS used to 'position' each dialog not be suffice?

Comment: Yes i want to specify start position to all modal without using different CSS for each modal. I suppose there could be possibility in JS, by capturing modal width and calculating top,left accordingly

Comment: So a globally defined CSS which will make all modal dialogs start at the same position, updated my answer which makes all modals right-align at the same position

Comment: No problem @Abhishek, happy coding! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/vertically-centering-bootstrap-modals) simple jS solution

```
$(function() {
    function reposition() {
        var modal = $(this),
            dialog = modal.find('.modal-dialog');
        modal.css('display', 'block');

        // Dividing by two centers the modal exactly, but dividing by three 
        // or four works better for larger screens.
        dialog.css("margin-top", Math.max(0, ($(window).height() - dialog.height()) / 2));
    }
    // Reposition when a modal is shown
    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', reposition);
    // Reposition when the window is resized
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        $('.modal:visible').each(reposition);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

here you have a link 
https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/oWRrva
you can able to open dynamically open model by size  using common function by passing size of a modal

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="openModel(1)">Modal 1</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="openModel(2)">Modal 2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="largeModel" onclick="openModel(3)">Modal 3</button>


<div id="myModal_default" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog" >
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>This is Default Size Modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

```
<script>
function openModel(size){
  $("#myModal_default").modal('show');  
   switch (size){
    case 1:{      
      $('.modal-dialog').css({'width':'40%',
                           'height':'auto', 
                          'max-height':'100%',
                          'max-width':'600px',
                          'top': '21px',
                          'left': '-269px'});
     break;
  }
case 2:{
$('.modal-dialog').css({'width':'65%' ,
                           'height':'auto', 
                          'max-height':'100%',
                          'max-width':'850px',
                          'top': '21px',
                          'left': '-105px'});
  break;
  }case 3:{
$('.modal-dialog').css({'width':'85%',
                           'height':'auto', 
                          'max-height':'100%',
                          'max-width':'1050px'});
    break;    
  }
default:{
  $('.modal-dialog').css({'width':'80%',
                           'height':'auto', 
                          'max-height':'100%',
                          'max-width':'950px',
                          'top': '21px',
                          'left': '-290px'});
  break;
  }    
 }
}
```

Comment: All the three modal don't have common start point. The top-left corner of all modal should be at same point....

Comment: Yah! Its possible @Abhishek you can able to load n- number of pages dynamically by passing  size of modal and content of the modal and etc..

Comment: You can add this code  in php/jsp/ or some other extension  directly include the page where ever you wan't  if its single page Application you some prefix in model for ex: prefix is based on your page name  id="PREFIX_myModal_default"

Comment: in the edited code i see you have mentioned top,left points. I don't want to mention any such points. Reason being there might be difference of +1/-1 px depending on the person developing.

Answer (score -1):

I would use data attributes to define my modal position, or maybe my modal class which might seems better, in my example i use positions, but i would suggest you use predefined classes, the same way 
example

```
<!-- html -->  
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-modal-top="21px" data-modal-left="-290px" data-modal-class="modal-lg" onclick="openModel()">Modal 2</button>


var btn = e.relatedTarget;
var topposition = btn.getAttribute('data-modal-top');
var leftposition = btn.getAttribute('data-modal-left');
//do your css here, use attribute value. 
$('.modal-dialog').css({'width':'65%' ,
                       'height':'auto', 
                      'max-height':'100%',
                      'max-width':'850px',
                      'top': topposition,
                      'left': leftposition});
//or if you will use class
var modalclass= btn.getAttribute('data-modal-class');
$('.modal-cdialog').addClass(modalclass);
```

Comment: You have told to add `data-modal-top="21px" data-modal-left="-290px"` in the code imagine if there are 500+ modal will i have to define for each modal.

Comment: that's why I suggested going with class not position, but i thought you want exact location that's why i included this in my answer